# O morfema do três

Tags: etimologia, números, morfema

Isto é uma pergunta na qual já penso há alguns anos. Daquelas coisas, que está sempre à frente dos nossos olhos mas, talvez não reparamos ou, nos habituamos a não reparar.

Português na coluna da esquerda; Latim na coluna da direita:

- Trê+s - Tres
- Ter+ço - Tercius
- Tri+ângulo - Triangulus
- Tre+ze - Tredecim

As minhas perguntas são estas:

1. Consideramos os três morfemas `Tre`, `Ter`, `Tri` como sendo [alomorfes](https://www.infoescola.com/portugues/alomorfia/) entre si? E portanto um mesmo morfema, com 3 formas diferentes? (Nestes casos o morfema é sempre raiz, excepto no triângulo onde é prefixo.)
2. Nesse caso o que chamamos ao +`s` ( o `s` aqui não podemos considerar como morfema do plural por a palavra ser singular), +`ço`, +`ângulo`, +`ze`?
3. No caso do +`ângulo` seria palavra composta, por justaposição. Mas no +`ze` do `Tre+ze` (olhando para o Latim) implicava o morfema `dez` ter sido invertido e perdido a consoante `d`. O que chamariamos a esse morfema, e ao processo que o inverteu?
4. Considerariamos o `Tre` e o `Tri` como sendo [apofonias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apophony) (e alomorfe) por troca de uma única vogal?
5. Podemos reparar que o `Três`, por acaso, até é considerado [protoindo-europeu](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%ADngua_protoindo-europeia) pelos linguístas. (Este ponto 5 não é pergunta, só uma nota que deixo.)
6. Numa análise `sintagmática` o que seria aqui significante, significado, etc?

Eu nunca encontrei um livro que explicasse isto com autoridade - agradeço referências na literatura. Acho uma pena, por serem numerais de uso quotidiano.

Answer (score 4):

Quanto à pergunta 3, acredito que a palavra em latim "tredecim" ([ˈt̪rɛ.d̪ɛ.kɪ̃]) tenha originado a partir, primeiramente, da perda do "m" final, seguida da passagem do latim ɪ > e; então a elisão do /d/ medial e a simplificação da vogal dupla. A variação de  e  era muito comum no período do português antigo, pois representavam as africadas t͡s e d͡z. No italiano, não houve a dita elisão, tornando-se tredici.
Tredecim > tredeci > *tredece >  *treeze > treze
Porém, acredito que essa pergunta seria melhor respondida no StackExchange de lingüística.

Edição: outra coisa que notei, é que de trēs temos tri-, de duo temos di- e de unus, temos uni- etc. Me parece um padrão.

Comment: Gostei muito da tua resposta. Acho que tem muito valor. Indicaste o caminho para ler e aprender sobre este processo de evolução fonética e de ortografia. Não respondi antes porque a metodologia que aqui partilhaste não é comum de encontrar. Sinceramente, fiquei "sem como". Só não vou aceitar a tua resposta, porque quero convidar outros membros a responder. Seria interessante  mais alguém elaborar ainda mais sobre esta questão. Por agora, não vou postar isto no SE de linguística. Obrigado @ᚹᛟᛞᚨᚾᚨᛉ.