# Etymology of Portuguese numbers 10, 20, 30...?

Tags: etimologia

I myself am a native Finnish speaker and the whole numbers 10, 20 and so on translate word for word as *ten, two tens* etc. Why in Portuguese are these said *dez* and *vinte*. The rest make sense to me as they are some form of the numbers *three, four, five*...

Comment: Portuguese is a romance language, so it's just because 10 in Latin is *decem* and 20 is *viginti*. Now you have to ask about the Latin etymology...

Comment: Severi, because Latin did it and, as Portuguese comes from Latin, we do as the Romans do. Though, you could say *dezena*, which is *ten* as a noun; for example, «três dezenas de queijo» (= «three tens of cheese»), but its use is stricter and less common than the cardinal numerals, and saying *X dezenas* is used usually only with things that are somehow separated in tens, as with the number system. Do you want a list for the etymology of *ten*, *twenty*, ..., and *ninety*, or do you want an explanation?

Comment: I really do not understand  this. In **English and Portuguese** no number such as 20 is said two tens. Also, do you mean etymology?

Comment: I asked the same question regarding the [variations of the *"three"* morpheme](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/6400) as we know them today.

Comment: If the answer addressed your question sufficiently please don't forget to upvote and [accept it by clicking the green check mark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkiIZ.png) on the left side of the answer.

Comment: If you look at German languages, "vinte" makes more sense, the inicial "t" being elided in Latin, and consequently in Portuguese.

Answer (score 5):

Well, if you go far, far, far, back, according to [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/viginti#Latin), *vinte* ultimately comes from Proto-Indo-European (PIE) *dwi(h₁)dḱm̥ti*, meaning ’two tens, two decades’; *dwóh₁* was ’two’ ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/duo#Latin)), and *déḱm̥* ’ten’ ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/decem);  these were reconstructed by linguists, not attested words). These eventually became *viginti*, *duo* and *decem* in Latin, which became *vinte*,  *dois* and *dez* in Portuguese.

Of the similarity between PIE *dwi(h₁)dḱm̥ti* and *dwóh₁* + *déḱm̥* very little survived into Classical Latin: only the *vi* in *viginti*, pronounced as *uí* (listen in [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/viginti#Latin)), was related to *uo* in *duo*; and *viginti* and *decem* ([listen](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/duo#Latin)) were pronounce with hard [g] and [k], two very similar sounds (as in *frango* and *franco*), and were both heirs to the *k* in *déḱm̥*. But even that was lost in Portuguese *vinte* and *dez*.